# Why can't "Git pull" pull all the branches from remote repo

Tags: git, git-pull, pull

I have a question about "git pull". Suppose I have a two remote branches "master" and "new_branch", when I use "git pull" and then use "git branch", only the "master" is shown. Why I can't see the "new branch"? I have to use "checkout new_branch" to get it shown on the local branch list. How does "checkout" work? Does it change to both local branch and remote branch?

Comment: @torazaburo `git pull` already performs a fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$ git fetch --all
```

it'll fetch all available branches from remote. You'll get a list like

> From 
>   * [new branch]      a_new_branch -> origin/a_new_branch
>   * [new branch]      b_new_branch -> origin/a_new_branch
>     3ea1234..1dz3  a_exist_branch_at_local -> origin/a_exist_branch_at_local
>     3ea1234..1dz4  b_exist_branch_at_local -> origin/b_exist_branch_at_local

Then just checkout the new one you want:

```
$ git checkout a_new_branch
```

for old ones (exist at local), you can

```
$ git checkout a_exist_branch_at_local
$ git merge origin/a_exist_branch_at_local
```

Comment: `git fetch --all` retrieves all the remote branches; `git fetch` by itself only retrieves the upstream branch of the currently checked-out branch.

Comment: @chepner seems so, but i can get all w/o the `--all`... anyway, updated the answer to append the `--all` option, thx for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

Git won't arbitrarily create local branches for you without you telling it to. However, it does keep track of the remote branches that it knows about.

```
$ git branch -a
```

will show you all the available branches on all of your remotes